# No campaign data found. Google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have problem with Google analytics v4 in my project. I'm receiving error No campaign data found.

Here is my code:
In activity file:

```
    private void reportGoogleAnalitics(String screenName){
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).newTracker(getString(R.string.google_analytics_id));
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    tracker = ((SBTApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    tracker.setScreenName(screenName);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```

And in my application class:

```
public class SBTApplication extends Application {
    private HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(getString(R.string.google_analytics_id));
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's just informational. Analytics is reporting that it didn't find any campaign tracking referrer data. If you haven't set up a campaign tracking receiver and are not installing the app via a referral link, when your app launches, it won't get any campaign data.

More details are available [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns)